# Combine search criteria from different column

Tags: datatables

I have a Datatable with 3 columns, and one search box.

Any keyword in the search box should match the **beginning** of either Column 1, 2 or 3.

---

**Example:**

Given keyword "apple", these 3 rows will match:

"**Apple** pie"  -  "dessert" - "handmade"

"New pear dessert" - "dessert" - "**apple** tree"

"New apple dessert" - "**apple** dessert" - "handmade"

This row should not match:

"Old apple dessert" - "dessert" - "handmade apple product"

---

**Code:**

For exact match on beginning of any of 3 Column:

```
searchBox.on('keyup', $.proxy(function (e) {
    // how to merge the search result?
    this._table.column(0).search('^' + searchBox.val(), true,
 false).draw();
    this._table.column(1).search('^' + searchBox.val(), true,
 false).draw();
    this._table.column(2).search('^' + searchBox.val(), true,
 false).draw();
}, this));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

According to the Datatable, we need a custom filter to achieve OR-condition on multiple columns: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11728/filtering-datatable-columns-using-or-logic

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var keyword = searchBox.val();
      keyword = keyword.toUpperCase();
      var productDesc = data[1].toUpperCase();
      var productExch = data[3].toUpperCase();
      var productSymbol = data[5].toUpperCase();
      if (productDesc.startsWith(keyword) || productExch.startsWith(keyword) || productSymbol.startsWith(keyword)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });

    searchBox.on('keyup', $.proxy(function (e) {
      this._table.draw();  //       this._table.search(searchBox.val()).draw();
    }, this));
```